# dual SOA client calls get SSL handshake error

Tags: java, ssl

I have a Java console app that iterates over a list of names and account numbers, and is going to do two things, which I call part A and part B.

Part A is to use the FedEx public SOA interface to create a shipping label.  This was the first part of the program I wrote, and it works fine.

Part B is using our internal SOA interface to write the FedEx tracking number to the customer's account.  The interface for this is basically

AddComment(String acctNum, String comment)

I wrote a stand-alone Java app to test part B, and it works fine.

When I added part B into the original program, part A still works, but I get an SSL handshake error when I try to execute part B.

The SOA interface for part B is using SSL.

I even put in a flag so that I can run the program as "part A only" or "part B only", and again, each one works individually, but when run together part B fails.

It smells like a case where something under the hood is being left in by part A such that part B no longer is working the way it did before.

It seems like this might be a not-uncommon problem when you have two different servers, both of which might have different protocols, etc.

So my real question is more general, and not just a coding issue.

Is there a way for me to reset my environment in my code, just before starting part B, so that it runs the way it does running stand-alone?

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by using the SSL context setDefault method, which seems to have done exactly what I suspected needed to be done, namely, to get me back to a clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by using the SSL context setDefault method, which seems to have done exactly what I suspected needed to be done, namely, to get me back to a clean environment.

```
sslCtx.setDefault(sslCtx);
```